# What is the meaning of this 'String#format' pattern?

Tags: java, receipt

During research for a task (create a receipt) I found the following code:

```
public class Kassenzettel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Einzelpreise - Waren
        double SEBox = 299.00;
        double Hauptplatine = 79.80;
        double Erweiterungsplatine =52.60;
        double Anschlusskabel = 19.50;
        double Firmware = 36.00;

        // Anzahl - Waren
        int anzSEBox = 1;
        int anzHauptplatine = 1;
        int anzErweiterungsplatine = 1;
        int anzAnschlusskabel = 2;
        int anzFirmware = 2;

        // Inhalt - Brieftasche
        double brieftasche = 550.00;

        // Gekaufte Waren
        double summe = 0;
        summe = summe + anzSEBox * SEBox;
        summe = summe + anzHauptplatine * Hauptplatine;
        summe = summe + anzErweiterungsplatine * Erweiterungsplatine;
        summe = summe + anzAnschlusskabel * Anschlusskabel;
        summe = summe + anzFirmware * Firmware;

        if (summe > brieftasche) {
            System.out.println("Nicht genuegend Geld in der Brieftasche");
        } else {

            System.out.println("____________________________________");
            System.out.println("DATCOM protelematik GmbH - Kassenbon");
            System.out.println("____________________________________");

            System.out.println(String.format("%-9s %2d x %5.2f EUR", "SEBox", anzSEBox, SEBox));
            System.out.println(String.format("%30.2f EUR", anzSEBox * SEBox));

            System.out.println(String.format("%-9s %2d x %5.2f EUR", "Hauptplatine", anzHauptplatine, Hauptplatine));
            System.out.println(String.format("%30.2f EUR", anzHauptplatine * Hauptplatine));

            System.out.println(String.format("%-9s %2d x %5.2f EUR", "Erweiterungsplatine", anzErweiterungsplatine, Erweiterungsplatine));
            System.out.println(String.format("%30.2f EUR", anzErweiterungsplatine * Erweiterungsplatine));

            System.out.println(String.format("%-9s %2d x %5.2f EUR", "Anschlusskabel", anzAnschlusskabel, Anschlusskabel));
            System.out.println(String.format("%30.2f EUR", anzAnschlusskabel * Anschlusskabel));

            System.out.println(String.format("%-9s %2d x %5.2f EUR", "Firmware", anzFirmware, Firmware));
            System.out.println(String.format("%30.2f EUR", anzFirmware * Firmware));

            System.out.println("____________________________________");

            System.out.println(String.format("%-9s %20.2f EUR", "Gesamt", summe));
            System.out.println(String.format("%-9s %20.2f EUR", "Gegeben", brieftasche));
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(String.format("%-9s %20.2f EUR", "Zurueck", brieftasche - summe));
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't understand the following line:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-9s %2d x %5.2f EUR", "Anschlusskabel", anzAnschlusskabel, Anschlusskabel));
```

I do understand what `System.out.println` is for, but can someone explain to me what exactly this is for: `"%-9s %2d x %5.2f EUR"`?

I think it's for the part where the code says:

```
SEBox      1 x 299,00 EUR
                        299,00 EUR
Hauptplatine  1 x 79,80 EUR
                         79,80 EUR
Erweiterungsplatine  1 x 52,60 EUR
                         52,60 EUR
Anschlusskabel  2 x 19,50 EUR
                         39,00 EUR
Firmware   2 x 36,00 EUR
                         72,00 EUR
```

but why and how?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) is used to format the string.

`%` is a special character denoting that a formatting instruction follows.

Type of argument is denoted by `d`, `f`, `x` and `s`.

- integers -  d,
- strings  - s,
- floating point -  f
- integers with hex format- x.

`%-9s` :  will format the string as it is. If the string has less than 9 characters, the output will be padded on the right.

`%2d`    : will format the integer as it is. If the number of digits is less than 2, the output will be padded on the left.

`%5.2f` : will format maximum 2 decimal digits of the number. The output will occupy 5 characters at least. If the number of digits is not enough, it will be padded.